# How can I localize routes with the nextJs and next-i18next like an URL alias?

Tags: javascript, express, next.js, i18next, next-i18next

I'm using `NextJs` 10.0.5 with `next-i18next` 8.1.0 to localize my application. As we all know `nextJs` 10 has subpath routing for internationalized routing. In addition, I need to change the page names by language. For example, I have a `contact-us` file inside the pages folder. When I change the language to Turkish, I have to use `localhost:3000/tr/contact-us`. However, I want to use `localhost:3000/bize-ulasin` to access the `contact-us` page when the language is Turkish. So there are two URLs and only one page file.

It works when I use custom routing with express js in the server.js file. However, when I want to access the "locale" variable within the `getStaticProps` function in the `contact-us` file, I cannot access it. The `getStaticProps` function returns undefined for "locale" variable when I use `localhost:3000/bize-ulasin` URL.

**server.js**

```
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");
const app = next({ dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler(app);

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;

    if (pathname === "/bize-ulasin") {
      app.render(req, res, "/contact-us", query);
    }else{
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    }
  }).listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("> Ready on http://localhost:3000");
  });
});
```

**/pages/contact-us-file**

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import { useTranslation } from "next-i18next";
import { serverSideTranslations } from "next-i18next/serverSideTranslations";

const ContactUs = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation("common");
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>Contact-Us</title>
      </Head>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export const getStaticProps = async ({ locale }) => {
  console.log(locale); // When I use the URL localhost: 3000/bize-ulasin, it returns undefined.
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common"])),
    },
  };
};

export default ContactUs;
```

How can I access the "locale" variable with getStaticProps? Or, how can I use the following URLs with the same page file?

```
->localhost:3000/contact-us
->localhost:3000/bize-ulasin
```

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem today. That's how I solved the issue.

First of all, delete the server.js file. With Next.JS 10, using server.js will create conflict with the i18n routes and you won't be able to get the `locale` data in `getStaticProps`.

NextJS has a beautiful method named [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites). We will use that instead of our server.js file. For example, if you have a page named `contact-us-file`, we can rewrite our next.config.js file as

```js
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config')

module.exports = {
    i18n,
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/contact-us',
                destination: '/en/contact-us-file',
            },
          {
                source: '/bize-ulasin',
                destination: '/tr/contact-us-file',
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

As you are already using Next-i18next, I hope you are familiar with the file that I am importing.

Now If you try to navigate `localhost:3000/contact-us` and `localhost:3000/bize-ulasin` you should be able to access your contact us page.

Comment: Is react router considering these redirects then ?

Comment: NextJS is actually handling the routing inside. No React-router involved here.

Comment: How do you implement language switching with this? (user stays on the same page after language switched, just locale changes)
I have         <Link href="/contact-us-file" locale={router.locale === "en" ? "tr" : "en"}>
But that won't take me to /bize-ulasin

Comment: @KhondokerZahidulHossain react router is involved in frontend or next router, i mean that the client router does not even know about redirects and uses still old values